# Cannot see controls on a MediaElement Player in Flexbox Modal in Android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, fancybox, mediaelement.js

I have a problem with a mediaelement player created within a Fancybox Modal. This is specific to an Android Device running 4.0.4.

On all iOS devices, new Android OS, Chrome, Firefox, and IE down to 7, when I create a new MediaElement player within a flexbox modal, I am able to view and interact with the controls.

But when I create it on the 4.0.4, the controls are hidden, though I can tap on them if I correctly guess where they are. But I cannot click on the video itself, which makes playing difficult. And the hidden controls are obviously a problem.

```
mediaelementjs_settings  =  {

                    loop    :  mej_loop,
                    pluginPath  :  options.plugin_path,
                    iPadUseNativeControls: options.mobile_native_controls,
                    iPhoneUseNativeControls: options.mobile_native_controls,
                    AndroidUseNativeControls: false,
                    alwaysShowControls: false,
                    error       :  function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                        $('<p class="' + options.component_type + '_error_message">' + options.error_msg + '</p>').insertAfter($(mediaElement).parent().parent().parent());
                        options.component_el.trigger(component_error, options);
                    },
                    success      :  function( mediaElement, domObject ) {
                        var meEl = mediaElement;
                        options.component_el.trigger(component_initialized, options);
                        if(mej_auto_start) {
                            // autostart requires a short timeout to work on several video formats. 100ms
                            // is hardly noticeable so we do it for everything for consistency 
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                mediaElement.play();
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    },
                    pauseOtherPlayers: false
                };


new MediaElementPlayer($(this).find('video:first'), mediaelementjs_settings);
```

I've played with z-index and other css fixes, but am currently stumped. Any ideas.

Comment: No, I meant Fancybox. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I determined it to be an issue where the overlay for Fancybox was somehow obscuring the controls. The solution was to set the positioning of the overlay to absolute instead of fixed. This could have impact on the way Fancybox worked so the script that inserts the video adds and removes a class which applies the appropriate style.